# How to print next character in string in absence of a character?

Tags: informatica

I have a string containing characters separated by space. Need to print that string in a specific format that is even if a character is absent from there the next corresponding character will be printed.

Example:
I have input strings like

INPUT RAW STRING

```
B D A E C

D B C

A E B

A B C D E
```

OUTPUT STRING

```
A B C D E

B C D 

A B E

A B C D E
```

Need solution in informatica

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far and what is not working

Answer (score 0):

Informatica is not the best tool to manipulate strings, as there is no parser, no array functions, and no loop construct natively.

It seems to me that your problem can be explained in a simpler way : the characters on each line must be sorted alphabetically.

You could use a Java Transformation and program this action in Java.

If you are on Linux, you could solve this problem with a short script:

```
while read line
do
    echo $line|tr ' ' '\n'|sort|xargs echo
done < yourfile.txt
```

In this script, the `while` loop reads each line of the file, and for each line it puts each character on a separate line with the `tr` command, then sorts the characters, and finally put together all characters from the same line in order.

As a last resort, you could do this with Informatica transformations if the number of characters on a line has a known (low) limit, because you shall create a field for each character of a line. You could use a Normalizer to put characters on separate records, sort them using a Sorter, assign rank values using an Expression, use an Aggregator to gather the characters from the same line, and an Expression to rebuild your lines.

I don't recommend this kind of solution, because it whould be very complex to achieve and to maintain.